# Continuous and invertible function

Tags: continuity, inverse-function

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^7}{15}+9x^3+25x+1$. If I want to prove that it is a surjective function, can I say that, since it is strictly monotone and continuous, then it is surely invertible and so surjective?

Comment: You did not prove that $f$ is striclty monotone and even if you do, it does not prove that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: But if a function is not strictly monotone I can conclude that it is not invertible not?

Comment: A strictly monotone function is invertible over its **range**. It may not be onto over its codomain (any superset of the range). For proving that the function is invertible when codomain is $\Bbb R$ you would need to prove that the range of the function is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But in this case in effect the function is trictly monotone in $\mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, there is some number $b$ such that $f(b) >y_0$.

Since $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$, there is some number $a<b$ such that $f(a) <y_0$.

The IVT shows that there is $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0$. This gives $f(\mathbb R)= \mathbb R.$

Comment: OK thanks. Saying that a function is surjective since it is invertible (beacuse it is strictly monotone) is not true?